# Issue on closing popup and showing message after doing any action in CiviCRM

Tags: civievent

Having issue when doing action like adding, updating or deleting anything from CiviCRM. Its not closing the popup and shows success message.

For Example,
When I am adding the new event registration from CiviCRM admin panel, Once I clicked on Save button, the registration got saved, but the popup is not closing and not showing the success message. Page stops with disabled buttons. Every time I suppose to refresh to see the saved records.

When I checked the ajax, One ajax request was called and succeed.

```
/civicrm/contact/view/participant?action=add&cid=50767&context=participant&snippet=json
```

Response

```
Object ID: 39731Operation: createObject Name: ContributionObject Ref: CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution Object
(
    [_relatedObjects] => Array
        (
        )

    [_component] => 
    [trxn_result_code] => 
    [id] => 39731
    [contact_id] => 50767
    [financial_type_id] => 4
    [contribution_page_id] => 
    [payment_instrument_id] => 4
    [receive_date] => 20180709022000
    [non_deductible_amount] => null
    [total_amount] => 0.00
    [fee_amount] => 0
    [net_amount] => 0
    [trxn_id] => null
    [invoice_id] => 
    [invoice_number] => 
    [currency] => USD
    [cancel_date] => 
    [cancel_reason] => 
    [receipt_date] => null
    [thankyou_date] => 
    [source] => HGS General Dinner- Tentative : Offline registration (by Mr. Manigandan V)
    [amount_level] => 
    [contribution_recur_id] => 
    [is_test] => 
    [is_pay_later] => 0
    [contribution_status_id] => 1
    [address_id] => 
    [check_number] => null
    [campaign_id] => 
    [creditnote_id] => 
    [tax_amount] => 
    [revenue_recognition_date] => 
    [_options:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_DB_DataObject_version] => 1.8.12
    [__table] => civicrm_contribution
    [N] => 0
    [_database_dsn] => 
    [_database_dsn_md5] => 
    [_database] => pantheon
    [_query] => Array
        (
            [condition] => 
            [group_by] => 
            [order_by] => 
            [having] => 
            [limit_start] => 
            [limit_count] => 
            [data_select] => *
        )

    [_DB_resultid] => 
    [_resultFields] => 
    [_link_loaded] => 
    [_join] => 
    [_lastError] => 
    [payment_processor] => 
)
{"buttonName":"upload","action":1,"id":22766,"status":"success","userContext":"\/civicrm\/contact\/view?reset=1&force=1&cid=50767&selectedChild=participant","title":"New Event Registration for Mr. Mani V","crmMessages":[{"text":"Event registration for Mani V has been added.","title":"Saved","type":"success","options":null}]}
```

Please Help!
I am using Drupal 7 with CiviCRM 4.7.29.

Answer (score 1):

Only that last line (starting with `{"buttonName`) should be present.  The rest looks like debugging code that was accidentally left in.

If this doesn't sound like something you may have done personally, try disabling extensions and re-enabling them one by one (or [half at a time](http://www.troubleshooters.com/ustep6.htm)) until you've found the troublesome extension.

UPDATE: Since this code isn't in an extension, it may be in core.  I searched the codebase for the words "Object ID", which appear in your output - and for me they only appear in `xml/schema/ACL/ACL.xml` and `CRM/ACL/DAO/ACL.php`.  If you search YOUR codebase for the words "Object ID" you're bound to find them somewhere else.

Comment: I am using only two extensions. I disabled both and tried, still getting same response.

Comment: @Manigandan I updated my answer, please check it out!

Comment: I checked and noticed another thing. That Object details comes only of that event is paid. Unpaid event are fine. That line is the only response. And also its making two more ajax calls which not happening if this object details come in the response.

Comment: As I am using the 4.7.29, it is in only one place - CRM/ACL/DAO/ACL.php